# Can anyone tell me why my web server cannot connect to a DB server?

Tags: linux, mysql

"Can't connect to MYSQL server" error. The DB is a separate server. http://dpaste.com/99702/

I typed "nc dbserver 3306" and it returned: [XXXXXX] 3306 (mysql) : Connection refused

Even in my GRANT options, I specified GRANT ALL TO . %...

My friend said that the web server is being prevented from establishing a TCP connection of any kind to that port.

I checked my.cnf...nothing special there. Could it be because of my IPTABLES?
--skip-networking option is NOT in my.cnf.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

111 usually is a generic "socket" connect error, i.e. *the packet never made it there*.  Without more info about how your firewall is set up, it could be caused by:

- Bad IP address
- Bad Port number (no service is running at that port)
- Bad routing setup (rare, but happens)
- Firewall is absorbing or rejecting the packet.  **This is most likely.**

Try connecting with a firewall exception and see if that works.  The exception should allow all traffic between the IP addresses of both machines, so there will be two rules - one for ingress and one for egress.

Answer (score 2):

Connection refused means it's not listening on your external IP address. I know you said you'd looked at your my.cnf, but make sure you do not have any of the following lines:

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
skip-networking
```

If you have bind-address, change it to be

```
bind-address            = *
```

If you have skip-networking, remove it.

If you've done these things, then check your firewall.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I had a similar problem as the OP and found this. In my case, bind-address  = * did not work. The server wouldn't restart. I removed the line altogether and now it works. I still need to investigate the security implications...

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check : try to connect on the PC with MySQL.

Here's what I'd do to check where the error comes from :

1. Try to connect directly : mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u [username] -p[password]
2. Try to connect directly **with the external IP** and the command line still on the MySQL computer : mysql -h 192.168.0.26 -u [username] -p[password]
3. Try to connect using command line from a distinct PC : mysql -h 192.168.0.26 -u [username] -p[password]
4. If everything works, the problems comes from the Apache Server configuration. Otherwise you'll be able to quickly guess where the problem comes from.

Comment: Sorry for the 4th : it may comes from the Apache Server configuration or the firewall where the Apache Server is.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, ensure that your MySQL server is actually listening on an external TCP socket. Do a `netstat` and see if you get something with 3306 in it and make sure that it is not just 127.0.0.1:3306 or something local like that.

```
# netstat -untap | grep 3306
```

Sometimes, MySQL is by default configured to listen only on local sockets. If that is the case, just edit your my.cnf file to listen on all interfaces. Otherwise, it is likely a networking problem.